# Listening to new enqueued messages using WCF Service

Tags: wcf, message-queue, ibm-mq

My message-queue is managed by IBM WebSphere MQ and I would like to be able to listen for new enqueued messages using a WCF service.

Each new message should trigger a call to my service with the new message as a parameter.

Do you know any way about how to create such a service and host it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebSphere MQ v701 or above, then you can use the WebSphere MQ Custom channel for WCF. Using the custom channel you can build and host services. You can find more details and samples [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un12000_.htm)

WMQ WCF based service can be hosted as a Windows service or a standalone application. It does not yet have capability to be hosted in an IIS or Windows Application Fabric/WAS.

Comment: As I understand from you - There is no way to automatically trigger a call to a WCF service when a new message is entering the queue?

Comment: When a WCF client calls a method exposed by the service, say 'printHello', the method automatically gets called on the service side. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @YairNevet: Did you ever get an answer to this...I would like to do the same - have WCF invoked when a separate application writes to the queue.  All the responses I have seen so far are about using WCF to write to the queue.